# Сравнение дат на php

Tags: php

Товарищи не пойму в чем дело. Вроде банальная штука сравнение дат. Но результат бывает разный.
Мне нужно сравнить полученную дату с текущей. Если полученная дата уже прошла, то время для игры истекло. Если полученная дата еще не настала то время игры еще активно.
Что я сделал

```
if($lotData['fdate_end']<=date("d.m.Y H:s")){
  echo "Время истекло";
}else{
  echo "Время есть";
}
```

Вроде как все нормально но когда получаю такую дату `22.04.2022 23:00` и сравниваю с текущей, то пишет что Время есть. Хотя это время уже прошло.

Тогда решил сделать так

```
if(time($lotData['fdate_end'])<=time(date("d.m.Y H:s"))){
    echo "Время истекло";
}else{
    echo "Время есть";
}
```

В таком случае когда получаю дату `22.04.2022 23:00` и сравниваю с текущей пишет что Время истекло(Как и нужно). Но когда получаю такую дату `19.07.2022 23:59` и сравниваю с текущей датой, тоже пишет что время истекло, хотя это полученное время еще не настало и должно было вывестись Время есть.

Что не так товарищи?

Comment: Ты же знаешь что функция `time` не имеет аргументов?

Comment: вы не даты сравниваете а лексикографически строковое представление дат. хочется даты строками сравниванить - пишите в формате Y-m-d хотя бы

Comment: Ваш первый код сравнивает не даты, он сравнивает строки. Ваш второй код пытается запихнуть в функцию time какие-то аргументы, но функция time не принимает никаких аргументов и показанный вами код должен выплёвывать Warning

Comment: Вы правы. Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как в комментариях отметили: Ваш первый код сравнивает не даты, он сравнивает строки.

Можно использовать пару способов сравнения дат:

1. Для каждой даты использовать `strtotime` и сравнивать их
2. Для каждой даты использовать **[DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)** и сравнивать их. `DateTime` удобно использовать в плане, что можно задать любой формат, а также есть нативные методы получения например разницы между интервалами, вычитать даты и пр.